# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'keyword")\'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

```
    url = 'test.com///"asdasdasd'
    name = "test"
    formatURL = url.replace("//","/")
    print(formatURL)

    conn= db.cursor()
    conn.execute("Insert Into website (URL,NAME) VALUES("{}","{}")".format(url,name))
    data_base.commit()
```

Most likely, Replace operation was not done correctly and I get the error below.

OUTPUT:

```
> test.com//"asdasdasd 
> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'test")\' at line 1')
```

How can I convert all "//" characters to a '/' character?

Comment: do not format vales for sql strings: use parametrized queries`conn.execute("Insert Into website (URL,NAME) VALUES( %s, %s)", (url,name))`

Comment: Oh, the replace was done correctly. You just have a SQL injection bug as Patrick points out.

Comment: Will this solution solve this problem? So is it a permanent solution proposition? Does it work in different SQL Injections?

Comment: Must probably yes - your string uses " to delimit itself and you use " before/after {} as well so python is confused about what is a string and what code and what not. ANd its simply the way to pass parameters into sql - you NEVER use format to give values.

Comment: You should be getting a Python syntax error from that line.

Comment: So how do I convert all "//" characters to "/"?

Comment: You do not do anything to the strings - if it prints() correct - the parametrized query will put the correct thing in. Does it print correctly?

Comment: Sorry , I didn't understand what to check :/

Answer (score 1):

You messed up the delimiters of your string. Don't use `str.format()` to format parameters into sql strings, use parametrized queries:

```
conn.execute("Insert Into website (URL,NAME) VALUES( %s, %s)", (url,name))
```

Here is the mess-up:

```
conn.execute("Insert Into website (URL,NAME) VALUES(" {} "," {} ")".format(url,name))
              111111111111111111111111111111111111111    222    333
                                         unrelated    {}     {}
```

all the `1` are one strings, all the `2` are another one and all `3` the third string. Both `{}` are unrelated curly braces(?) and the `.format(url,name)` is only applied to `")"` (aka `3`) which is not a valid format string.

Simply use parametrized queries - they are safer and much easier:

Source: https://xkcd.com/327/ ([License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/))

[image: https://xkcd.com/327/]

and syntax hints for lots of languages: https://bobby-tables.com/python